# ARM deployment multi-line string with escaped quotes

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to deploy this ARM template

```
/* example_template.json */
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-08-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "var": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "
                echo ${VARIABLE}
            ",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "some description"
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "ouput": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[string(parameters('var'))]"
        }
    }
}
```

which successfully outputs what I want:

```
    "outputs": {
      "ouput": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "\n                echo ${VARIABLE}\n            "
      }
    }
```

The problem is, if I am trying to use this in a bash script, `$VARIABLE` may have a space in it, hence I need to output to be

```
    "outputs": {
      "ouput": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "\n                echo \"${USER}\"\n            "
      }
    }
```

to prevent argument splitting.

So, I have tried to edit my template to include the quotes

```
/* example_template.json */
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-08-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "var": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "
                echo \"${VARIABLE}\"
            ",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "some description"
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "ouput": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[string(parameters('var'))]"
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives me a `validate` and `create` error:

```
> az deployment group validate -f example_template.json -g resource-group-name
Failed to parse 'example_template.json', please check whether it is a valid JSON format
```

This seems to only happen with the multi-line string - if I put the whole `defaultValue` on a single line i.e.,

```
"defaultValue": "echo \"${VARIABLE}\""
```

it is successful again.

I need to use a multiline string as this variable is for a long deployment script which would be infeasible to put on one-line.

I believe this is a bug due to the parser only failing with the multiline string, but am unsure where to report it!

Does anyone know what a possible solution to this could be?

Thanks,
Akhil

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no significance to do multi-line manually like you did.

As you can see, the **type** of this `"var"` parameter is `"string"`, so it should be a **string** in `"defaultValue"`, thus the reason you got the error message. Even it worked without error when using PowerShell command like `"New-AzDeployment"` ,but the result is same.

As you want to "use a multiline string as this variable is for a long deployment script", you can try do this to make the defaultValue to be a string:

```
"parameters": {
    "var": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "VARIABLE={value1}\n echo \"${VARIABLE}\"",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "some description"
        }
    }
},
```

The output should be:

```
VARIABLE={value1}
echo "${VARIABLE}"
```

---

Actually az command is based on python, Power Shell command is based on c#, which made them parse json differently.

**About how Azure CLI parse json**, it starts reading `defaultValue` string with `"`, and cannot find the opposite `"` in the same line, then the error occurs.

**About how Power Shell parse json**, it starts reading `defaultValue` string with `:`, and read the whole content included in that `:`.

[Deploy ARM template with Power Shell.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-powershell)

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply. I know that I can use `\n` as a line break, however, if I did this the line would be over 1000 characters long and a nightmare to debug, edit, or update in the template. The question is more about why inserting the line break as a visual one rather than `\n` breaks the `json` parser when escaped double quotes are used as, like you pointed out, they are exactly the same. I'm not sure I understand your point about type - in all my examples the type is `"string"` - could you please clarify that?

Comment: I certainly agree that there is no significance to doing multi-line manually. The ARM template parser (in this case the `az` cli) seems to disagree though :(

Comment: @AkhilNair , I agree with your comment about az cli, and updated my answer. You can use Power Shell command to meet your need.